# Variable values used in xsl:element for XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am currently trying to write an XSLT where I am able to use a variable that I have previously defined with a value from my original XML

An example of my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:content="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:content:3.0" 
    xmlns:offer="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:offer:3.0" 
    xmlns:title="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:title:3.0"
    xmlns="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:core:3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:core:3.0 MD-SP-CORE-I02.xsd urn:cablelabs:md:xsd:offer:3.0"
    version="1.0" >


<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" media-type="text/xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:output method ="xml" doctype-system="ADI.DTD"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<!-- Define Variables -->
<!-- uriID = ProviderID/AssetDiscriminator/AssetId -->
<xsl:variable name="uriIdProvider" select="'indemand.com'"/>
<xsl:variable name="episodeTitle" select="'//PACKAGEDETAILS/VERSION_SERIES_TITLE'"/>

<!-- Build output Xml in CableLabs Format-->
<xsl:template match="/">


<ADI3>
<xsl:copy-of select="document('')/*/@xsi:schemaLocation"/>
<xsl:comment> Assets for the Series </xsl:comment>

<Asset
uriId="{$uriIdProvider}/Title/"
xsi:type="title:TitleType">

<xsl:element name="title:TitleBrief">
    <xsl:value-of select="{$episodeTitle}"/>
</xsl:element>

</Asset>


</ADI3>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Where my issue lies is in the end where I am trying to define the xsl:element title:TitleBrief with a previously declared variable episodeTitle.

What I would like my output to look like is:

```
<Asset uriId="indemand.com/Title/" xsi:type="title:TitleType">
  <title:TitleBrief>Haunting, A (S8)</title:TitleBrief>
</Asset>
```

Could some one help me figure out where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Instead of:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="{$episodeTitle}"/>
   ```

   use:

   ```
   <xsl:value-of select="$episodeTitle"/>
   ```
2. (I am guessing) instead of:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="episodeTitle" select="'//PACKAGEDETAILS/VERSION_SERIES_TITLE'"/>
   ```

   use:

   ```
   <xsl:variable name="episodeTitle" select="//PACKAGEDETAILS/VERSION_SERIES_TITLE"/>
   ```